# How to gather pixel data from cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Im trying to gather pixel rgb values from an active cv2.VideoCapture method my code can scan a 20x20 pixel area and average out all the rgb values but it only works on an image, using VideoCapture doesn't work please help here is the code:

```
loop = True
red = 0
green = 0
blu = 0

def AutonomousCar():
    global loop
    global red
    global green
    global blu
    red = 0
    blu = 0
    green = 0
    import cv2

    roadimg = cv2.imread(r"roadimg.jpg")

    loop = True
    startPoint = [50, 50]

    changeVar = 1
    downVar = 1
    bluval = []
    greenval = []
    redval = []

    while loop:
        if downVar >= 21:
            loop = False
        if changeVar <= 20:
            changeVar += 1
            startPoint[0] += 1
        elif changeVar >= 20:
            changeVar = 1
            startPoint[1] += 1
            startPoint[0] = 50
            downVar += 1
        presentPixel = tuple(startPoint)
        pixelData = roadimg[presentPixel]
        fixpixelData = tuple(pixelData)
        fixfixpixelData = str(fixpixelData)
        fixfixfixpixelData = fixfixpixelData.replace("(", "")
        fixfixfixpixelData = fixfixfixpixelData.replace(")", "")
        ffffpixelData = fixfixfixpixelData.split(", ")
        ffffpixelData = list(map(int, ffffpixelData))
        bluval.append(ffffpixelData[0])
        greenval.append(ffffpixelData[1])
        redval.append(ffffpixelData[2])

        red = sum(redval) / len(redval)
        green = sum(greenval) / len(greenval)
        blu = sum(bluval) / len(bluval)
        red = int(red)
        green = int(green)
        blu = int(blu)
AutonomousCar()
red = red
green = green
blu = blu
```

BTW: the reason some of this code seems kind of useless is that I'm using this code like a library so that I can access it from another python file in the same file location

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work?' can not print the result out?

Comment: Please be more specific with the "doesn't work" part :P

Comment: i answered that question below you're answer down below

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Minimal is important!

Comment: if i make it more clear do you know the answer cause if not I'm not changing anything

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'it doesn't work?' can not print the result out?

I modified it. It works well for me.

```
loop = True
red = 0
green = 0
blu = 0


def AutonomousCar():
    global loop
    global red
    global green
    global blu
    red = 0
    blu = 0
    green = 0
    import cv2

    roadimg = cv2.imread(r"roadimg.jpg")
    print(roadimg.shape)
    loop = True
    startPoint = [50, 50]

    changeVar = 1
    downVar = 1
    bluval = []
    greenval = []
    redval = []

    while loop:
        if downVar >= 21:
            loop = False
        if changeVar <= 20:
            changeVar += 1
            startPoint[0] += 1
        elif changeVar >= 20:
            changeVar = 1
            startPoint[1] += 1
            startPoint[0] = 50
            downVar += 1
        presentPixel = tuple(startPoint)
        pixelData = roadimg[presentPixel]
        fixpixelData = tuple(pixelData)
        fixfixpixelData = str(fixpixelData)
        fixfixfixpixelData = fixfixpixelData.replace("(", "")
        fixfixfixpixelData = fixfixfixpixelData.replace(")", "")
        ffffpixelData = fixfixfixpixelData.split(", ")
        ffffpixelData = list(map(int, ffffpixelData))
        bluval.append(ffffpixelData[0])
        greenval.append(ffffpixelData[1])
        redval.append(ffffpixelData[2])

        red = sum(redval) / len(redval)
        green = sum(greenval) / len(greenval)
        blu = sum(bluval) / len(bluval)
        red = int(red)
        green = int(green)
        blu = int(blu)
    return red, green, blu


red,green,blu = AutonomousCar()
print(red, green, blu)
```

You can see the result here:
[image]

Comment: no it works for me too i want it to print out average rgb values of a live video feed from my webcam but if I replace roadimg = cv2.imread(r"roadimg") with cv2.VideoCapture(0) and the other lines of code you need to access the webcam it doesn't work I get an error

Comment: just wondering what did you change about the code